# Regarding Marker interfaces in java

Tags: java

I am a new bie to marker interfaces but I explore them by looking through decomplier , interfaces  like serilizable and clonnable , I have gone with the following url also for better understanding http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/01/what-is-marker-interfaces-in-java-and.html

Now my query is that as we design our normal interface in our implementation, can we also design our marker interfaces , if yes then please advise how to design them and if no then please explain the reason.

The only query that I have please advise can we make our interfaces also to act like as a marker one , i want to create my own marker interface as java have provided please advise can I create my own interface to act like a marker one.

Comment: What do you mean "design our marker interface"?

Comment: Re `"we design our normal interface in our implementation"` -- please clarify as I don't understand this statement. Also there is no design needed for marker interfaces. They're just markers, that's it. They have no body, no method declarations, so what designing do you think is required of them?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Please advise as I want to create my own marker interface .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a marker interface, you need to create an interface with no methods:

```
interface MyMarker {
}
```

and you're done. Now if your class implements this interface, it is a MyMarker type class. That's it.

**Edit**
You state:

> Apart from using built in marker interface for making a class Serializable or Clonnable. One can also develop his own marker interface. Marker interface is a good way to classify code. You can create marker interface to logically divide your code and if you have your own tool than you can perform some pre-processing operation on those classes..Now please advise how can I give any indication to java complier while my classes implementing that marker interface as in the case of serilizable marker interface happened ...

You initially asked about marker interfaces, and above is how you can create them. You can have any class implement them, and this marks the class for distinction as having been marked. What you do with that information is up to you. As to the magic of serialization, that's something that I am no expert at, but I expect that there's a lot of reflection going on behind the scenes.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this any way?

Comment: Thanks a lot. but in the url suggested above it was mention that ...Apart from using built in marker interface for making a class Serializable or Clonnable. One can also develop his own marker interface. Marker interface is a good way to classify code. You can create marker interface to logically divide your code and if you have your own tool than you can perform some pre-processing operation on those classes..Now please advise how can I give any indication to java complier while my classes implementing that marker interface as in the case of serilizable marker interface happened

Comment: Thanks again I want to explore that how special preprocessing happens at the backend when our class implements the marker interface and how do we send the special signals to java complier.

Comment: @user2045633: Consider having a look at the source code for serialization to see how the compiler uses this information, that is as long as not too much of the code is native code.

Comment: yeah sure Thanks a lot for explaining , it was really helpful.